# Sci Fi book about ESP. Each person with ESP has just one power

Tags: story-identification, books

Book circa 1971. 5 persons with near-death experiences demonstrate more than 1 power. Theme of giant moths flying through space and aliens searching for them.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: The title either contains more information relevant to the question, or contradicts the information in the question. Clarifying this would be helpful.

Comment: So ESP is a known thing, but before these five individuals, no one has had more than one power? And how do the giant moths fit in there? Do they tie in with the psychic powers somehow?

Comment: Do you mean that each person has one power and that there are differences between the powers of the five people?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/166082/old-science-fiction-book-about-telepathy-telekinesis-pyrokinesis-and-mental-co

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure this one's come up before.  The likeliest answer is "Sentinels From Space" by Eric Frank Russell.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinels_From_Space

There are actually more like 12 powers and humans change into the "giant moths.

Comment: There's mention of the multiple talents at https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1898793.Sentinels_from_Space

Comment: Reading between the lines, it sounds like everyone only has 1 power, and the protagonists are pulling some kind of con to make it seem like a multi-talented individual has arisen.  Which fits pretty well with the question.