# Find title of a book about a race searching for giant space moths

Tags: story-identification

I read this library book in 1972. The opening is an image of giant moths flying through space.

The story takes place on a planet (Earth?) where people each have one psychic power. Except that four people after near-death experiences have multiple powers.

Comment: Welcome to the site, you're off to a good start but I recommend looking at [this checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337) to see if you can add in any more details!

Comment: Possibly the same as [Sci Fi book about ESP. Each person with ESP has just one power](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/214298/sci-fi-book-about-esp-each-person-with-esp-has-just-one-power).

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/166082/old-science-fiction-book-about-telepathy-telekinesis-pyrokinesis-and-mental-co

Answer (score 4):

Almost certainly Eric Frank Russel's *Sentinels From Space*.

Space travel and exposure to cosmic radiation has led to a dozen types of mutants appearing, notably telepaths, hypnos and insectivocals (who can control insects). The central characters appear to have some new powers which the recognised types don't possess, and are taken for extraterrestrial spies, but all is not as it seems.

> They are not aliens, but humans who have died and entered a next phase of existence, like a caterpillar turning into a butterfly. They are standing guard over Earth against hostile aliens who would destroy their human "larvae".