# Sci-fi book about psychic "humans" protecting/hiding Earth from the approaching Denebs

Tags: story-identification

Man has colonised Mars and Venus. Radiation-induced psychic mutants are now common (except on Earth) and are being used to wage clandestine war against Earth.

Following an alarming near contact between long-range Earth exploration ships and something rather alien, some super psychics are recruited to stop the rebels. The super psychics are actually "possessed" by higher intelligences that are hiding Earth (which is their nursery) from the approaching telepathic "racist" Denebs.

Comment: Hi Andysaurus and welcome to SciFi StackExchange. It is not clear what you are asking. If you want help to identify the story you have described i recommend you read through [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/105008) list and see if you can make things clearer.

Comment: @Andysaurus   People from the star Deneb are called Denebians, not "Denebs".

Comment: However, it the story that one wants to identify uses "Denebs", and that is what one remembers, it seems daft to confuse potential answerers by using the wrong name.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/166082/old-science-fiction-book-about-telepathy-telekinesis-pyrokinesis-and-mental-co (but please accept the answer below if it is correct)

Answer (score 12):

[Sentinels from Space](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1898793.Sentinels_from_Space) by Eric Frank Russell

> When the mutants of the Mars and Venus colonies sought independence, the World Council tried to protect Earth's interests. But even bigger things were at stake: Full-scale war would attract the attentions of the deadly Denebian aliens, who were slowly advancing towards Earth.
>
> Only David Raven - and a few others like him - knew about the Denebians. But Raven had powers no human or mutant had every dreamed of, and he was looking out for humanity...

Comment: Don't forget to turn direct quotes into quotes by adding a > at the start of the sentence

Comment: The book never calls them "Denebians", note.  I just checked.  They are "Denebs" and we are not told where they come from.